# How can I use GROUPBY date with Android Room Database?

Tags: android, datetime, group-by, android-room

I'm trying to create a Room Database with Date, using this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data .

I enter the Date in this format: `Fri Aug 21 16:05:30 GTM 2020`
and I can insert several items with the same date, but with different times. How can I use query that GROUPBY by the same date (the same day) ?

I try with `SELECT * FROM table GROUPBY date`but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using `SELECT * FROM user_table GROUP BY date(user_date/1000, 'unixepoch')`